# Some div are created automatically in react

Tags: reactjs

I have a react code like below

```
 <div className="grid-container">
  <header>
    <Header />
  </header>
  <main>
    {(userInfo?.isAdmin === false || !userInfo) &&
      location.pathname === '/' && <Carousel />}
    <div className={userInfo?.isAdmin ? 'row  stretch left' : 'row'}>
      {userInfo?.isAdmin && <Sidebar listItems={listItems} />}
      <Content />
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer className="row center">All rights reserved.</footer>
</div>
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zhM1.png)

In that screenshot, some div are created automatically. In component , There is no such a div in between sidebar class and row class. But I don't Know how it comes. Please help me..
Sidebar component:

```
export default function Sidebar(props) {
   const items = props.listItems;
   const location = useLocation();
   return (
     <ul className="sidebar">
        {items.map((list) => (
        <li key={list.link} className={`sidebar__item`}>
        <Link
        to={`/${list.link}`}
        className={`sidebar__link ${
          location.pathname === '/' && list.link === 'dashboard'
            ? 'active__link'
            : location.pathname === '/' + list.link
            ? 'active__link'
            : ''
        }`}
      >
        {list.name === 'Dashboard' ? (
          <ColumnsGap className="sidebar__icon" />
        ) : list.name === 'Products' ? (
          <BoxSeam className="sidebar__icon" />
        ) : list.name === 'Orders' ? (
          <BagCheck className="sidebar__icon" />
        ) : list.name === 'UsersList' ? (
          <People className="sidebar__icon" />
        ) : (
          ''
        )}
        {list.name}
      </Link>
    </li>
  ))}
</ul>
);
}
```

Content Component:

```
export default function Content() {
 const userSignin = useSelector((state) => state.userSignin);
 const { userInfo } = userSignin;

 return (
  <>
  <Route path="/product/:id" exact component={ProductScreen}></Route>
  <Route path="/cart/:id?" exact component={CartScreen}></Route>  

  </>
 );
}
```

ProductScreen:

```
 export default function ProductScreen(props) {
  return (
  <>
  {loading ? (
    <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>
  ) : error ? (
    <MessageBox>{error}</MessageBox>
  ) : (
   <div className="">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-3">
          <div className="col-1">Image</div>
          <div className="col-1">Image Details</div>
        </div>
        <div className="col-1">
        </div>
     </div>
   </div>)
}
```

Cart Component:

```
export default function CartScreen(props) {
   return (
     <div>
       <h1 className="mb-1">Shopping Cart</h1>
       <div className="row top">
          <div className="col-2">
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>)
   }
```

Like above all components are enclosed with div tag or empty tag.But there are more empty div tag are produced automatically.

Comment: Need to check the code of your Sidebar component and Content component

Comment: Seems to come from <Content />

Comment: @skmak this user is not using `listItems` as boolean, he/she is passing the data. @Sowmiya your problem is in `<Content />` so, whoever or whatever is consuming this code, is giving you those empty `divs`.

Comment: Hi @jperl, In <Content /> Route elements only placed. But In all Components I didn't have this much empty div.

Comment: @matiaslauriti, I need some more explanation

Comment: Where is this happening to you ? In `/product/123` or `/cart/123` or `/cart` or all of them ?

Comment: You now have to have a look in either ProductScreen or CartScreen depending on where you're at.

Comment: Can you please show us the code of these components and the path?

Comment: @matiaslauriti In all page, I have faced this issue,

Comment: @jperl, I have used about 20 components inside Content component. But In all component, there is only one div wrapper.In that situation only one div should be placed. But here automatically more divs are placed

Comment: Can you show us `ProductScreen` and `CartScreen` components ? Any of those are having these problems

Comment: @matiaslauriti I have added the components in question itself